# Why is a background process stdin link on a terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

When i start

```
bash test.sh &

ps
 457349 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
 458609 pts/5    00:00:00 sleep
 458656 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
1107610 pts/5    00:01:47 zsh

lsof -p 457349

COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    457349   pk    0u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5
bash    457349   pk    1u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5
bash    457349   pk    2u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5
```

Why is a background process stdin link on a terminal?

0u - /dev/pts/5

He is in the background and what I write in the terminal is not noticed on it

Comment: If you change you put `while : ; do echo 'Hoppa!" ; sleep 1; done` in your `test.sh`, you'll notice that there is a link between your process and the terminal. Also, if you put `read someting` in your `test.sh`, you'll notice that `test.sh` stops. That also is a clear indication, that there is a link between your process and the terminal.

Comment: @LjmDullaart yes, does this mean that stdin stdout is really attached to the background script? but if I press ctrl+C the background process doesn't stop

Comment: Do not confuse STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR with having a link to the terminal. If you press ctrl-C, the shell that you are talking to will send a SIGINT-signal to the foreground process. Likewise, the STDOUT of the `ls` in `ls | cat` is not directed to your terminal, but is the STDIN of `cat`

Comment: When you start a process in the background using the & symbol, it gets detached from the terminal and runs independently. It no longer receives input from the terminal or sends output to it.

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost No, he sends output to terminal.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Those. in fact, ctrl + c, etc., stop working. because they are send at the process in the foreground. But does stdin stdout work the same way? 
How is a foreground process different from a background process on the system? Where else besides std is it connected to the terminal?

Comment: @LjmDullaart  "If you press ctrl-C, the shell that you are talking to will send a SIGINT-signal to the foreground process." -- not quite correct. the shell would not see ctrl-c. the kernel (terminal driver) directly sends SIGINT to foreground processes.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is a background process stdin link on a terminal?

There is no particular reason why that should not be.  Unless its standard streams are explicitly redirected, a process inherits them from the process that launches it.  When that process is an interactive shell running in a terminal (for example), those streams are generally associated with the terminal.

> Why is a background process stdin link on a terminal?

Putting a process in the background does not disassociate it from its controlling terminal or disconnect or redirect its standard streams.  Rather, it is about what happens when the process attempts to interact with streams connected to the terminal, and about where signals generated by the terminal driver go.  It is not unusual for background processes to have their stdin connected to a terminal.

> He is in the background and what I write in the terminal is not noticed on it

Yes, that's large among the practical implications of being "in the background".  But note that the process could be switched into the foreground, after which it would consume input from the terminal.  Having stdin connected to a terminal does not necessarily mean that you can consume input provided via the terminal.

Comment: How is a foreground process different from a background process on the system? Where else besides std is it connected to the terminal?

Comment: @Betflop, the defining characteristic of a foreground process is exactly that it has a controlling terminal and can interact with it.  It can read from that terminal and write to it, via its standard streams or otherwise, and it receives signals from the terminal when certain events occur, such as a `SIGINT` when a ctrl-C is typed at the terminal.  This is related to, but not dependent on, where its standard streams are connected.  Every process can have a controlling terminal.

Comment: Yes, but how is it work at the Linux level? i have two processes they have stdin stdout to my terminal but why do first accept ctrl+c commands and the other one doesn't?

Comment: @Betflop, This is a discrete concept, not one emerging from other behaviors.  POSIX defines functions for manipulating which is the foreground process group in any given session.  The Glibc manual has a pretty good description of everything involved, including details of how they apply to implementing a job-control shell.  This is a reasonably good entry point to that: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html.  If you want something deeper then you'll need to browse source code.